# friends of friends in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to do something like friends of friends in mongodb... In mysql it was

```
select friend_id from friends where user_id IN (select friend_id from friends where user_id = id)`
```

Comment: sry? i cud not get the extreme use of shorthands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform multiple queries unless you are able to store your data as nested data structure inside one document

Answer (score 0):

embeds friendship?

and in your friendship model have a friender and a friendee with request and accept date.

Comment: that wont work exactly... its more of a following/follower kind of relation... so embedding wont do much good...